# How can I split large post request?

Tags: javascript, http

For example, there is some user who trying to register on a social network. He had loaded personal data and several photos in form.

```
const json = {
  name: 'Jhon',
  lastName: 'Travolta',
  photos: [
    File, File, File, File, File, File, File, File, File, 
  ]
}
```

The whole json weight is more than 100mb.
Server can receive only 20mb requests.

How can I slice such POST request without server request size increasing?
Eg there are some HTTP options which apply such behavior?

Comment: why not make multiple http requests?

Comment: Unfortunately pictures, like other media files, can easily pass the 20mb limit. So, the increasing of the server's limit size is practically mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Upload each file and the textual data separately. Once user selects images to upload, take each File object, assign it a UUID and send it off for upload in a separate HTTP request. You save the assigned UUID in the photos key in your JSON.

Post the JSON with UUIDs to the server rather than the JSON including the photo contents. Your JSON with UUIDs won't exceed 20 MB limit. Also, individual files will also be most likely less than 20 MB.

Steps:

1. Disable submit button
2. Let user select images
3. For each image, create a UUID, and send HTTP request with that UUID to `upload` endpoint on your server
4. Use the generated UUID for each image rather than image content
5. Enable submit button again when all images are uploaded
6. On submit, serialize and post the JSON with UUIDs to server